# Multiple RDS farm session hosts for load balancing?

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop-services, rds

I am setting up an RDS farm, intending to host terminal access software for access to a mainframe.

We'd like to set up multiple RDS servers for redundancy and load balancing. To accomplish this, is it correct that only multiple session hosts would need to be installed and added to the collection, to handle the application and remote session loads? E.g., only one license server, connection broker, etc, would be needed and can be installed on the first session host?

Also, I am assuming that the client software would need to be installed independently on all session hosts - simply adding a session host to the collection will not allow it to serve the software?

Thanks

Comment: You're correct on all points.